# Which() case insensitive in R

Tags: r

I want to return the index of a string in a dataframe, but I need to have it as case insensitive, I tried using `tolower()` but it didn't gave the required results. I am using

```
which(dataframe  == "matching string", arr.ind = TRUE)
```

The data in dataframe is mixed case so I need to match it to required string .

Comment: `sapply(dataframe, tolower)`

Comment: Wow it worked. Thank you so much, what if my string contains "-"  or some other character but in dataframe there is no such "-", what should be done to match them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tolower` function won't work on a dataframe.  `which` is designed for vectors and matrices, and works on dataframes by converting them to matrices first.  So you need to do that explicitly:

```
which(tolower(as.matrix(dataframe)) == "matching string", arr.ind = TRUE)
```

Comment: Wow it worked. Thank you so much, what if my string contains "-"  or some other character but in dataframe there is no such "-", what should be done to match them

Comment: You can use `gsub` to make other changes, e.g. `gsub("[-+]", "", x)` will give a version of `x` with all `-` and `+` characters removed.  Use this to take out all the characters you want to ignore.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I want to learn r to master over it can u please tell me some online resource from where I can start from basic to all analysis and graphs etc

Comment: Start with "An Introduction to R", which ships with R, and is linked into the help system.  It's kind of old, but will get you the basics.  There are tons of choices after that, and I don't really know them, so ask on the R-help mailing list for advice on sources for any particular topic that interests you.  (I think a question like that is off-topic on StackOverflow; too much opinion.)